# hcxdumptool problem

Tags: scripts, kali-linux-tools

```
hcxdumptool -o capture.pcapng -i 5ce0c53ef9c7 --enable_status=1 --filterlist_client=filter.txt --filtermode=2


initialization...

failed to backup current interface flags, ioctl(SIOCGIFFLAGS) not supported by driver: No such device

failed to init socket
hcxdumptool need full and exclusive access to the adapter
as well as write permission for the dumpfile
that is not the case
try to use ip link to bring interface down/up
and iw to set monitor mode

terminating...
failed to get interface information: No such device
failed to set interface down: No such device
failed to restore old SIOCSIWMODE: No such device
failed to restore old SIOCSIFFLAGS and to bring interface up: No such device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message! "`hcxdumptool need full and exclusive access to the adapter
as well as write permission for the dumpfile
that is not the case`".

This is a system level request, thus must be done as `root` through `sudo`

```
sudo hcxdumptool -o capture.pcapng -i 5ce0c53ef9c7 --enable_status=1 --filterlist_client=filter.txt --filtermode=2
```